# vue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ... of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, netlify

I'm using vue@2.1.3 and the [vue official webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) to build an app.

When developing locally, I often see the warning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ... of undefined`, but the HTML can be rendered successfully. However, the HTML can't be rendered when it's deployed to Netlify with `npm run build` command. So I have to treat this warning seriously.

I learned from [here](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/3953/cannot-read-property-warning/2) that it's because "the data is not complete when the component is rendered, but e.g. loaded from an API." and the solution is to "use `v-if` to render that part of the template only once the data has been loaded."

There are two questions:

1. I tried wrap `v-if` around multiple statements that's generating the warning but personally I think this solution is verbose. Is there a neater approach?
2. "warnings" in local development turn into "fatal errors" (HTML can't be rendered) in production. How to make them the same in both environments? e.g. both of them issue warnings or errors?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just use `v-if` on a common parent to all the elements in your template relying on that AJAX call, not around each one.

So instead of something like:

```
<div>
  <h1 v-if="foo.title">{{ foo.title }}</h1>
  <p v-if="foo.description">{{ foo.description }}</p>
</div>
```

Do

```
<div>
  <template v-if="foo">
    <h1>{{ foo.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ foo.description }}</p>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This works. While I wonder if this is the only solution since I don't really want to remember to put a `v-if` on top of every component that has AJAX call. But your solution has already removed a large part of my headache. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure how much data you're loading but you might be able to load it all up front then when that's ready show the rest of your app.

Answer (score 10):

have you tried to initialize all the data you need? e.g. if you need `a` `b` `c`, you can do:

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1,
    b: '',
    c: {}
  },
  created(){
    // send a request to get result, and assign the value to a, b, c here

  }
})
```

In this way you wont get any `xx is undefined` error

Answer (score 8):

Guys are right but I can add something.
If there is possibility that your root element in the condition can be undefined for some reason, it is good practice to use something like that: `v-if='rootElement && rootElement.prop'`. It will secure you from getting `cannot get property prop of undefined` as when `rootelement` is undefined, it will not go further in checking.

Comment: Is rootElement predefined or what ?

Answer (score 2):

2021 vue3

we can use like this

```
props: {
    form: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
 setup(props, context) {
    console.log(props.form)
```