# Access nested prop in child component

Tags: vue.js

I'm passing data to child component like this:

Parent.vue

```
<template>
 <vote-buttons :data="data">
 </vote-buttons>
</template>

props: {
 comment: {type: Object}
},
setup(props) {
 const data = {
  'score': props.comment.score,
  'hasVoteOfUser': props.comment.hasVoteOfUser,
 }

 return { data }
}
```

Child.vue

```
props: {
 data: { type: Object }
},

// or

props: {
 data: {
  score: { type: Number },
  hasVoteOfUser: { type: Boolean }
}
```

When i'm accessing `{{ data.score }}` in child component, i'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: $props.data is undefined` and just `{{ data }}` renders whole object `{ "score": 1, "hasVoteOfUser": true }`.
Why rendering of one property doesn't work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my fault, there was another component on the same page, which used the same child and did not provide `data` prop.
This question was useful for me: [Uncaught TypeError: $props.currentQuestion is undefined Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014513/uncaught-typeerror-props-currentquestion-is-undefined-vue)